# How can I save gmail messages or threads to a local file

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to write a script that will write either gmail messages, or complete threads, with a given label (probably, unless some can tell me how to detect if something is ticked) to local files.

I am alright with retrieving the messages or threads, it's the last bit, saving locally.

I have looked at creating a document from the contents of the messages and doing a getAs("application/PDF"), but I still run into the issue of how to save that locally.

To put this another way, I am trying to automate the "Print All" "Save as PDF" functionality.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

ContentService has a capability called [downloadAsFile](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_textoutput#downloadAsFile) which allows you to set up your web app such as that when the user visits a link a file starts downloading.

You can see an example of this here in [Github](https://github.com/entaq/GoogleAppsScript/blob/master/ContentService/Addressbook-VCF/Code.gs) and I do a walkthrough in [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=JRGzVdliQOQ#t=1510s).